# How many times a year are company results or announcements usually made?

Tags: stocks

Company results and other periodic company announcements nearly always have an effect on stock prices. I am unclear as to how often these are typically made - is it every year, every six months, or every three months?

Would I be right to guess that most or all large companies announce something that affects their stock price every three months?

Comment: For publicly traded companies in the US, reports are issued quarterly (every 3 months). However it is worth noting that only the annual report is required to be audited.

Answer (score 2):

> Would I be right to guess that most or all large companies announce something that affects their stock price every three months?

No. *Earnings* are reported every three months, but they don't always have an effect on stock price (and even if they did, you can't know for certain what *direction* they will move). Often, earnings reports have little effect on stock prices, since analysts try to *predict* earnings, and those predictions are baked into the current price.

Other news, like product announcements, corporate actions, etc. are not released on a pattern. They are released based on when the events occur and when management decides to make the news public.

Answer (score 0):

They only *have to* present one annual official report.

Otherwise, it is their free choice to make further announcements when they want to, quarterly, monthly, every day, or whenever they feel like.
Obviously, having too many or too unpredictable announcements reduces public interest or positive reception, so many tend to establish a predictable rhythm.

So your answer is - there is no clear prediction possible; you need to look at each specific company to see if they follow a rhythm and which.
Quarterly is not uncommon, but not the rule and in no way binding.

Comment: In the US, public companies are required to file financial statements **quarterly** as well.